# Getting title attribute when <span> inside <span> with javax.swing.text.StyledDocument

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I set this text to `JTextPane`, with contentType `text/html`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><title>Test document</title></head>
  <body style="font-family:monospace">
    <p title="t1" style="color: #FF0000;">
      This is <span title="t2" style="color: #00FF00;">new <span style="color: #0000FF;">more</span> title</span> test
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

My goal is, getting title attribute to display as ToolTip when mouse-over. I learned that it is possible overriding `JTextPane.getToolTipText(MouseEvent event)` and using `JTextComponent.viewToModel(Point pt)`.

So far, `This is` and `test` displays tooltip `t1`, and `new` and `title` displays tooltip `t2`, as expected.

However, I can't retrieve `title="t2"` when I mouse-over the word `more`; instead, it displays tooltip `t1`.

Using the [JEditorPaneStructureTool](http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneStructureTool.html), I got this structure:

[image: Document structure for example html]

It seems that there are some issues for structuring  inside .

Is there some way to get correct title attribute?

Comment: I am afraid it's not possible. As you can see in the tool there is no span in span in the DOM structure. Instead each span is converted into LeafElement with own set of attributes. The attributes has reference to parent and the P's title is displayed. Is it possible to avoid span in span?

Comment: My conclusion regarding this issue is that `javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument` can't handle more than very simple structure; I just found that elements that has multiple `class` didn't rendered correctly. I have to make HTML document as simple as possible (for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a trick for this problem, knowing the limitations of HTMLDocument. Try to replace your outer spans by fonts like :

```
    This is <font title="t2" style="color: #00FF00;">new <span style="color: #0000FF;">more</span> title</font> test
```

I'm pretty sure it will work. Give these font a specific class. This way you can revert them to span when exporting the html content.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works well for the given HTML. However, this trick wouldn't work when HTML document becomes "more complex," due to fundmental limitation of HTMLDocument......

Comment: I can't say... It depends very much on what you try to achieve. It's true that HTMLDocument is pretty limited, but I managed to find a trick for almost all of these limitations and now it works as expected for me. But it's true that most of other people just switched to JavaFX components. Good luck.